How to do classical perturbation theory with Poisson brackets
I need some help computing the behavior of variables $c_i$ in a classical system with Hamiltonian $H$ using perturbation theory. There are as many $c_i$ variables as there are degrees of freedom. I'd like to do it with Poisson brackets
$$\dot c_i = [c_i, c_j] \frac{\partial H}{\partial c_j}.$$
Let's say I already have the zeroth order solution $c^{(0)}(t)$. Goldstein's book says that
$$\dot c_i^{(1)} = [c_i^{(0)}, c_j^{(0)}] \frac{\partial H^{(1)}}{\partial c_j}$$
if $c_i^{(0)}$ are constants (Eq. 12.24). I was wondering if this is still true if $c_i$ are not constant? If you just plug in $c_i = c_i^{(0)} + c_i^{(1)}$, you get
$$\dot c_i^{(1)} = [c_i^{(0)}, c_j^{(0)}] \frac{\partial H^{(1)}}{\partial c_j} + [c_i^{(1)}, c_j^{(0)}] \frac{\partial H^{(0)}}{\partial c_j} + [c_i^{(0)}, c_j^{(1)}] \frac{\partial H^{(0)}}{\partial c_j}.$$
I'm worried that the last two terms might not vanish for non-constant $c$. Maybe I'm not fully understanding the Poisson bracket and the last two terms simply don't exist?
Thanks!
P.S. I know that the standard thing is to use angle action coordinates, but my particular Hamiltonian makes that messy and I'd love to be able to do this for specific, non-canonical $c_i$.

... assuming here that $[a,b]$ is your notation for the classical Poisson bracket?

Yes, sorry that was unclear.
